# ViewPropertyAnimator scale a 9patch

Tags: android, view, fragment, android-animation, android-dialogfragment

I have a `dialogfragment` with a `9patch` background. When I scale the fragment with `animate()`, the `9patch` gets stretched. I'd like for it to expand according to the 9 patch logic(ie, repeat certain areas of the image to construct a full background). How do I do this?

Comment: A `9 patch` can only work if it is set as a **background**. Not knowing anything about your code or your 9 patch or nothing, I can't tell you more than this.

Comment: @DerGolem, yes. Its the background of my view. When I do a `view.animate().scaleY(3.0f)`, the 9patch gets stretched. I'd like for it to resize as per its logic

Comment: `I'd like for it to resize as per its logic` But its logic is **to be stretched** (on the marked areas). It will always be as big as your View.

Comment: @DerGolem If that was the case I'd be happy, but its losing its dynamics. The parts of it that shouldn't stretch stretch. The drop shadow gets all elongated.

Comment: By not knowing anything about your 9 patch, my only advice can be: visit this page: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/